# pthreadとSCHED_FIFOによる優先度スケジューリングについて

Tags: linux, c

RTOSのプログラムをLinuxのAPIでシミュレーションできないかと考えています。同じコードをPCでテストすることが目的で、リアルタイム性はあまり気にしてません。
manページ等をみると、スケジューリングポリシーにSCHED_FIFOを指定すると優先度の高いスレッドがブロックされない限り、低優先度のスレッドはブロックされるといった記述がありました。そこで、下記のサンプルコードを試してみましたが期待通りの動作にはなりませんでした。

具体的には、高優先度のスレッドがwhile文で無限ループしているので低優先度のスレッドのprintfが永久に実行されない、というのが期待する動作です。なぜこのサンプルコードではスレッドの切替が行われてしまうのでしょうか？

**@user20098さんのコメントを受けて、カーネルバージョン等の追記**
Windows10(64bit)上のVirtualBoxでUbuntu16.04(AMD64)をインストールしてテストしています。

```
$ uname -a
Linux vagrant 4.4.0-87-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 18 12:55:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>


static void* prio_high(void* arg)
{
    volatile int i = 0;
    while (1)
        i++;

    return NULL;
}

static void* prio_low(void* arg)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", i++);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sched_param param1;
    struct sched_param param2;
    pthread_attr_t attr1;
    pthread_attr_t attr2;
    pthread_t th1;
    pthread_t th2;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr1, SCHED_FIFO);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr2, SCHED_FIFO);
    assert(ret == 0);

    param1.sched_priority = 9;
    ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr1, &param1);
    assert(ret == 0);
    param2.sched_priority = 10;
    ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr2, &param2);
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = pthread_create(&th1, &attr1, prio_low, NULL);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_create(&th2, &attr2, prio_high, NULL);
    assert(ret == 0);

    while (1)
        sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: カーネルのバージョンとCPU種別は何でしょうか? 質問文に追記頂けると助かります。

Comment: root 権限で実行していますか?

Comment: 一般ユーザーでもrootでも結果は同じでした

Comment: "echo -1 > /proc/srs/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us"が必要なのかもしれません。(参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722615/sched-fifo-process-with-priority-of-99-gets-preempted , https://qiita.com/rarul/items/88d3e803d8456f50db01)

Comment: sched_rt_runtime_usをしましたがダメでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問で挙げられているサンプルコードに`pthread_attr_setinheritsched()`は必要です。( @masm と同回答)
これがないと、親スレッドのスケジュールポリシーを子スレッドが引き継ぎます。

```
/* 記述例 */
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr1, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr2, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
```

また、Linuxのpthread実装では、SHCED_FIFOを指定するにはroot権限が必要ですので、
rootユーザでプログラムを実行する必要があります。

ただし、この状況でもVirtualBoxの仮想マシンのCPU構成がマルチCPU環境だと、
優先度の低いスレッドにもCPUが割り当たるので、サンプルコードの2スレッドは両方動作します。

＃このことは仮想マシンだけでなく、物理マシンにも当てはまります。

マルチCPU構成環境で実行しているのであれば、CPU数を「1」にするか、`taskset`コマンドで
使用するCPU数を「1」に制限した状態でサンプルプログラムを実行すれば、期待通りの
動作(`printf()`の出力がされなくなる)になると予想します。

---

なお、サンプルプログラムのスケジュールポリシーがFIFOになっているかどうかは、

```
/proc/<PID>/task/<TID>/sched
```

疑似ファイルを確認するとわかると思います。(`<TID>`はLinuxのスレッドID)
(`policy`行の値が「1」であればFIFOのはずです。(※コメントの記述(`priority`)は誤りで、`policy`が正しいです)

Comment: tasksetでCPU数を1にすると期待した動作になりました。優先度の低いスレッドにもCPUが割当たってしまうのですね。優先度の低いスレッドをブロックしたいという用途ではSCHED_FIFOは使いづらいということがわかりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_attr_setinheritsched()` をする必要があります。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>


static void* prio_high(void* arg)
{
    volatile int i = 0;
    while (1)
        i++;

    return NULL;
}

static void* prio_low(void* arg)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("i = %d\n", i++);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sched_param param1;
    struct sched_param param2;
    pthread_attr_t attr1;
    pthread_attr_t attr2;
    pthread_t th1;
    pthread_t th2;
    int ret;

    ret = pthread_attr_init(&attr1);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr1, SCHED_FIFO);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr2, SCHED_FIFO);
    assert(ret == 0);

    param1.sched_priority = 9;
    ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr1, &param1);
    assert(ret == 0);
    param2.sched_priority = 10;
    ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr2, &param2);
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr1, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr2, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    assert(ret == 0);

    ret = pthread_create(&th1, &attr1, prio_low, NULL);
    assert(ret == 0);
    ret = pthread_create(&th2, &attr2, prio_high, NULL);
    assert(ret == 0);

    while (1)
        sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

これを root 権限で実行すると、`printf()` の出力は出ません(最初に少しだけ出ますが)。

ただし、prio_high が高い優先度で実行されるため、sshd も処理をすることができず、
ctrl+c すら届かなくなります。

---

上記に加え、下記 sysctl の設定ではどうでしょうか?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287561/sched-fifo-thread-is-preempted-by-sched-other-thread-in-linux

```
# sysctl -a | grep sched_rt
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
# sysctl kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 1000000
# sysctl -a | grep sched_rt
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 1000000
#
```

(tanalab2 さんのコメントと異なり、1000000 にしてます)

ただし、sched_rt_period_us の時間中の sched_rt_runtime_us を realtime thread に使い、残りの時間を SCHED_OTHER thread に使う、というものですので、変化ないかもしれませんが。

Comment: こちらの環境では状況は変わりませんでした。GCCのバージョンは5.4.0。コマンドはgcc -O2 -o test main.c -lpthread; sudo ./test です。

Comment: @paruwo 回答に追記しました。

Comment: sudo sh -c "echo 1000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us" と950000も両方試しましたが変化なしでした。

Comment: VirtualBoxで作成した仮想マシンがマルチCPU構成の場合、優先度の低いスレッドも実行されます。CPU数を「1」にするか、`taskset`コマンドでプロセスが使用するCPUを1つに限定すると、期待通りの動作になると思います。

Comment: スレッドのスケジューリングがFIFOになっているかどうかは、`/proc/PID/task/TID/sched`をcatした際に表示される`priority`の値を確認するとよいです。(「1」ならFIFOになっている)

Comment: @user20098 回答として書いていただけませんか?

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = pthread_create(&th1, &attr1, prio_low, NULL);
assert(ret == 0);
```

で最初のpthread、th1が作られます。他にpthreadは無いので、最高優先度を持つpthreadとなりますから、prio_lowのルーチンが実行されます。

その後で

```
ret = pthread_create(&th2, &attr2, prio_high, NULL);
assert(ret == 0);
```

とth1よりも高い優先度を持つpthread、th2が作られますが、それに先立って th1が実行されたという事象が取り消される訳ではありません。

＝＝
th2のpthreadを作るほうが先、th1のpthreadを作るほうが後にすると、動作が変わるかと思われます。

Comment: th2を先に生成するようにしましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。